# constexpr causes a GCC warning when used with string literal

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, constexpr, string-literals

The below code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>


int main( )
{
    const char* const str = "This is a constant string.";

    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

However, this one gives a warning:

```
    constexpr char* const str = "This is a constant string.";
```

Here:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   37 |         constexpr char* const str = "This is a constant string.";
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is this a bug in GCC? I'm converting a string to a pointer that is pointing to a `constexpr char` array. Is this warning valid?

Now making the pointer itself `constexpr` prevents it from being compiled at all:

```
    const char* constexpr str = "This is a constant string.";
```

Here:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'constexpr'
   37 |         const char* constexpr str = "This is a constant string.";
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~
```

Why can't a pointer be constexpr?

Comment: `constexpr` applies to the pointer itself, NOT to the thing it's pointing to, it should be  `constexpr const char* str`

Comment: @Kaldrr Aha I got it. Now is there a way to make the type itself `constexpr`? I mean something like `constexpr (constexpr char*) str`? Is there any benefit in doing this?

Comment: Short answer, no. `constexpr` isn't really a part of the C++ type system, there isn't a specific type of pointer to point at `constexpr` variables, only the pointer itself is `constexpr`. Use pointers to `const` instead as `constexpr` implies the variable to be `const`

Comment: @Kaldrr Thanks for the info. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you are using constexpr here is not the issue. You are trying to store a string literal in a char* const which is not a pointer to immutable data (which the string literal is), but rather a pointer with a constant address. A string literal can be stored as const char* or const char* const instead.

```
const char* str = "This is a constant string."
```

Adding constexpr would look like this:

```
constexpr const char* str = "This is a constant string."
```